# How to capture response error/message in separate route?

Tags: node.js, api, middleware

I just want to capture the response error from a middleware function, it works if I write the code as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = require('./routes');

//monk.mongoList();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extented:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(expressValidator([]));

var port = process.env.PORT || 8978;


router.get('/',function(req,res,next) {
  var error = Error('Article is not found');
  next(error.message);
 return res.send("Hello World!");
});

app.use(function(err,req,res,next) {
  console.log(err + "TET");
})


app.listen(port);
```

but I want to separate the following code:

```
app.use(function(err,req,res,next) {
  console.log(err + "TET");
})
```

and use it as follows:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = require('./routes');

//monk.mongoList();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extented:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(expressValidator([]));

var port = process.env.PORT || 8978;


var test = require('./util/test')

app.use(test.logger);


app.use('/',router);


app.listen(port);
console.log('test node API ' + port );
```

**util/test.js**

```
module.exports.logger = function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.log('LOGGED')
  next()
}
```

**/routes/index.js** **EDIT:** I just edited the /routes/index.js file to make it more simple

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var url = require('url');



router.get('/api', function(req, res, next) {

    var err = "this is error";
    var error = Error (err)
    var data = { data: "Succuss"}
    if (err) {
      next(error.message)
      res.json({message:err})
    }else {
      res.json(data);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

When add the above code, nothing appear in the console.

Comment: Notice in `/routes/index.js` you never call `next()` in your route, you only do `res.status()` to indicate an error. Since you do that, you've sent a response and so your logger middleware never gets invoked since express has determined your server response as completed.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts but in app.js ```test.logger``` is called before the routes so It should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for quick feedback guys, @PatrickRoberts I just tried as you suggested. The error now print it in the command line but it's not captured by the `test.logger` function. Do you know, how can I make it? Also note I just edited the /routes/index.js file error and output method.

Comment: You put the logger afterwards. You can't capture an error if you're passing it after the logger is already invoked